# Setting tabindex in dynamic table vertically then horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that is currently generating dynamically created textboxes in a table format.  The users are requesting that the tab order be changed from horizontal-vertical to vertical-horizontal.  I know that you can use the tabindex attribute to control the tab ordering, but I can't for the life of me figure out the right way to get the sequential number properly for the textboxes.  I guess this is more of a math question than anything else!

FYI, the textboxes are made while looping two different collections.  First collection looped to make the rows, for each row, second collection (which is a property of the first collection objects) is looped to create the columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need three variables to get this to work:

- Total number of rows
- Current row index
- Current column index

You can then achieve the vertical tab order by setting the tabindex to:

```
totalRowCount * currentColumnIndex + currentRowIndex + 1
```

For a five-row, three-column table the above calculation would render the tab order as:

```
1   5   10
2   6   11
3   7   12
4   8   13 
5   9   14
```

**Updated:** Wil, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the example. I also checked the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex)  (which I probably should have done first) which clarifies the behavior:

> elements that do not support the
>   tabindex attribute or support it and
>   assign it a value of "0" are navigated
>   next. These elements are navigated in
>   the order they appear in the character
>   stream.